# Maven Gwt Archetype errors

Tags: java, gwt, maven

So I tried to get the Maven Gwt archetype up and running. So some background info, I got Maven 3.0, and I have JDK 1.7 in Eclipse.

I ran the archetype, imported the project, and had a bunch of warnings and errors, I solved most of them but this one: GWT SDk servlet.jar was missing in WEB-INF/lib
So I searched stack overflow, and used someones suggestion of using quick-fix to synchronize them. Now I get a warning saying that I have not J2SE1.5 installed.

Do I need J2SE1.5 to run my web app? Why is JDk 1.7 not enough?

Next, I get the warning

```
  Classpath entry com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.GWT_CONTAINER will not be exported or published. Runtime ClassNotFoundExceptions may result.
```

Which I also have no clue why it is saying that.

But I am able to run the clean install gwt:run Maven goals without any problems.

I could suppress the warnings but my ADD would kill me, I'd rather understand the issues if I am going to just ignore them.

Comment: have you set the compiler version? Like here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371737/maven-confused-about-jre-been-used

Comment: Any JDK above 1.6 is suitable for GWT. Please post your pom file

Comment: romedius I tried to change it, it did not help, and the POM is not change from the archetypes, I will edit my question to include it though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `GWT_CONTAINER` entry in your build-path with a Maven project, then you're doing it wrong (`gwt-maven-plugin` archetype most probably does it wrong, but I don't have the patience to fix all its warts and nobody else seems to bother; maybe we should simply get rid of it).

You should first install the Google Plugin for Eclipse (GPE), which works hand-in-hand with M2Eclipse (M2E) to autoconfigure the project when it detects it's a GWT project (makes use of the `gwt-maven-plugin` IIRC).

Then make sure you don't have any `.project`, `.classpath` or `.settings/` files/folders and import your Maven project in Eclipse. M2E and GPE should do everything for you. In the event that GPE doesn't add the GWT nature to your project, go check "Google Web Toolkit" in the project preferences, you'll see that GPE will have automatically selected the `gwt-user` from your POM as the *GWT SDK*.

See http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/WorkingWithMaven (which suggests avoiding the `gwt-maven-plugin` archetype).

All in all, it's easier to simply start from scratch: add a dependency on `gwt-user` and add the `gwt-maven-plugin`, then do everything else with GPE wizards in Eclipse.
You might also find https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot Thomas, I will try those github archetypes. I am really confused as to why google's, what I understood to be, main archetype is not working though.

Comment: Hey Thomas I am trying to get your web app to run, But I am getting a build failure on step 2 in start the development mode. Could not resolve dependencies for project could not find shared artifact

Comment: Follow the instructions in the README ;-) and do not hesitate to report issues on GitHub. And BTW  gwt-maven-plugin is *not* a Google project.

Comment: Ah sorry, got he README wrong! do a first `mvn install` before `mvn gwt:run`

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I decided to try my luck with gwt default archetype, and I got it working without any problems thus far. I do have a question for your folder structure in your web app archetype. I would like to know why you have a war in both client and server? If you could I would love to hear your reasoning for setting up the project the way you did.

Comment: `war` for client is mostly to have GPE autoconfig project in Eclipse; in another project, I was building a zip using the maven-assembly-plugin; in the end, the war or zip is used as an overlay in the server module. See also http://tbroyer.posterous.com/announcing-gwt-maven-archetypes-project In the long term, the client module would have a `gwt-app` type rather than `war`; I just need to find time trying it out ;-)